# Reading csv file in C, strtok not returning what I am expecting?

Tags: c, strtok

I am trying to write a C program to read a CSV file and calculate something and printing a line to the screen. However, the values I am storing in my array do not seem to match up with my input file.

For 1,2,2,3

I get an average of 50.0000000 printed to the screen. Can anyone offer some advice? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
...
fclose(input);
}
```

Comment: `double data[100];` --> `char *data[100];`, `data[j++] = *p;` --> `data[j++] = p;`

Comment: and `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*p` is a character, so you are putting ASCII codes into `data`.  You want the values these represent, or you can (which your later use of `atof` suggests) declare `data` to be an array of strings.